# MySQL Optimizing Query With IN

Tags: mysql, performance

```
SELECT `listener` ,
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `call_time` ) ) ) AS total_time,
COUNT( `listener` ) AS number
FROM calls
WHERE listened_date = '2013-05-09'
AND type in ('column1','column2')
AND id
IN ( SELECT id
FROM calls
GROUP BY CONCAT( name, ' ', when ) )
GROUP BY `listener`
```

This query is working so slow and making other queries not working in same time. How can i make this lighter?

I think IN make it slower. What is alternative in this case?

Comment: have you indexed "id"?

Comment: @ile No. Is `IGNORE INDEX (id)` enough?

Comment: just the opposite - creating an index on a column will increase querying speed greatly, although it will grow the memory size of the db a bit. You can create an index on your table with "CREATE INDEX id_index ON calls (id) USING BTREE;". Note that 1. this should be an addition to optimizing your mysql query (other answers) 2. you should reindex the table after adding new records ("OPTIMIZE TABLE calls"), i.e. it is not a good solution if you have frequent inserts/deletions on the table

Comment: @ile Average 9 insert, update, delete query per second working in table.

Comment: there is an average of 9 inserts, delete, updates on the table? :| are you sure, seems highly exaggerated?...
 How many records do you have?

Comment: @milesh IN statement using same table as FROM ? if yes you can not use  at all IN statement

Comment: @Justin I answered in other comment.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe ?:

```
SELECT c.`listener` ,
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(c.`call_time`))) AS total_time,
       COUNT(c.`listener`) AS number
FROM calls c
WHERE c.listened_date = '2013-05-09'
  AND c.TYPE IN ('column1',
                 'column2')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 0
              FROM calls c2
              WHERE c2.id = c.id)
GROUP BY c.`listener`
```

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM calls c2 WHERE c2.id = c.id) GROUP BY c.listener LIM' at line 1`

Comment: I don't think you can do more than this... maybe just summing call time can be like this - `SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(c.call_time))`

Comment: About your edit; i was using that for `CONCAT`; it eliminates records with same listener and same time. This query doesn't do same thing.